# Параллельное программирование

Tags: excel, access, visual-basic, vba, office

Если не ошибаюсь, то VBA не обладает функционалом для параллельного выполнения программ.

Однако, я где-то читал, что можно создать несколько экземляров Application и дать каждому свою работу.
Подскажите, как это правильно сделать, да еще и динамически(Что бы можно было перед стартом задавать кол-во процессов) ?

Т.е банальный пример:

Есть 4 папки с файлами, я хочу дать каждому Application свою папку для получения имен файлов и заноса их в БД Access.

Если я сделаю так:

```
otherApp.run Macros
```

то меня не отпустит до тех пор, пока не закончится макрос в другом приложении, а хотелось бы пойти дальше и запустить макрос на других.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Многопоточности в VBA как таковой нет. Но, тем не менее, возможно добиться от него похожего поведения.
Как это делается можно посмотреть, например, по следующим ссылкам:

[Simulating Multithreading in VBA using Excel](http://www.databison.com/simulating-multithreading-in-vba-using-excel/)

[Multi-threaded VBA](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/05/multi-threaded-vba.html)

[asynchronous communication between Excel instances](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/215874-asynchronous-communication-between-excel-instances.html)